# Does SpecFlow have an issue in with the phrase "I should"

Tags: c#, specflow

Scenario Outline:
gift card

```
Given a user has purchased a gift card from a retail store  
When they complete their redemption with a <Card status>  
Then I should <Email status>
```

Examples:

```
| Card status | Email status          |
| Valid       | receive an e mail     |
| Invalid     | not receive an e mail |
```

I have written the above feature scenario a long time ago in my test case and updated the specflow file to its newest version (1.9) about a month ago and have ran it since then and has worked perfectly. However, yesterday I ran my test case and I was getting an ambiguous step definition error on the line "Then I should "

I have tried many changes such as changing it to "Then I should  asdgasgqrg" while respectively changing the step definition file. I also changed it to "Then I should asgasg" and got the same issue.

I have checked for all other occurrences in the entire solution for "Then I should " and my file has the only occurrence.

When I changed it to "Then a", it finally worked. So I became curious and changed my step to "Then I must " and respectively changing the step definition and it worked.

I also changed the phrase "I should" to "I must" in another feature file that was causing the same issue and it worked.

So here is my question: Is there some issue (formatting or syntax wise) within specflow that does not like the phrase "I should"?

Comment: This "ambiguous step definition" error happens when the regexes in your step definitions match two different bindings.  It might not be as simple as searching for "I should". The best way to identify the underlying issue would be to leave your feature file with the "I should" text, comment out the step binding that you expect it to bind to, add a break point on the "the I should" step and debug the test.  If you step into another binding, then there was actually an ambiguous definition.  If not, something else is at work.

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you flatten the scenario outline into the two different scenarios? 
Theoretically that's all that SpecFlow is doing and it might help to identify your problem more easily.

Answer (score -1):

I am using `I should` and it is working perfectly fine :

```
Given I have events present in the Grid
When I click on navigation module on left Panel
Then I should be able to view the X module
```